# Media File Conversion Library For .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, video, video-encoding

Was wondering if there exist out there any paid for or free .NET libraries (dlls) that performs file conversions, specifically for video. E.g .mov to .avi or 3gp etc.

I've been googling all morning and found plenty of programs and sites that perform these tasks but we need top be able to build solution into our own application.

Many thanks for your help.

tony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try [FFLib.NET](http://www.intuitive.sk/fflib/)